# Linux OS for Mac PowerBook g3 (1998)

Tags: linux, mac, operating-systems, graphics

So I got a PowerBook G3 off EBay (I don't know why, I just did) and it arrived.   Now that I have it i realised that is nearly useless running Mac OS 9.  My question is : Is there a Linux distro, like DSL, that would be able to run on it? Or maybe is there a way to get a web development IDE for it?

Computers Specs: [EBay Link](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Apple-Macintosh-PowerBook-G3-14-1-TFT-233-MHz-Laptop-M4753-/221176407040?pt=Apple_Laptops&hash=item337f242400)

(NOTE: I have a 20gb hard drive, I will put it in once I figure out how I go about doing that.)

Comment: Or you could use XPostFacto to install OS X: http://eshop.macsales.com/OSXCenter/XPostFacto/

Comment: @phw what is the latest version this will run with XPostFacto?

Comment: 10.4 it seems. However, there are some known problems: http://eshop.macsales.com/OSXCenter/XPostFacto/Framework.cfm?page=XPostFacto3.html

Answer (score 0):

Try mintppc.org the best i've found so far , I'm running a powerbookg3 wallstreet, I'm experimenting with other versions of linux so far this is the best.
i couldn't get mintppc 11.0 to install. system specs---
mac powerbook g3  310mb ram 40g harddrive. OS= mintppc 9.2.  ------if you don't mind command line installs try cruxppc.org

Comment: I cant get my PowerBook to start from the disk.  How do I do this?